# android utc time conversion issue

Tags: java, android, datetime, utc

I need to convert a **UTC** time string into my local time, the code works fine in my PC when I run it on **Eclipse**, however, I get incorrect results on **Android**. I am stuck, can someone help.

Below is the code I am using, an example input would be "**2017-04-24 1:00 AM**", this will yield a result of "**11:00 AM**" which is what I am expecting, however, it always return "**10:00 AM**" on Android.

```
public String convertUTCTime(String utcTime) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm a");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse(utcTime);
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
        sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
        String format = sdf.format(date);
        return format;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "Not applicable";
}
```

Comment: Are you considering the possibility of day light savings?

Comment: @james Use valid date format to parse date you are using 24 hour format with ap/pm its not valid check https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html link for your understanding.

Comment: please replace yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a to yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a this will give you valid result

Comment: HH:mm stand for 24 hour format and hh:mm a stand for 12 hour format

Comment: What time zone is your PC running? And you Android device? You may want to print out `tz` and study the difference. Its `toString` method produces a funny format, but some of it is readable if you try hard, and in any case you can tell whether it’s the same on both devices or not.

Comment: If you want to make do with the oldfashioned classes, you may find it a bit simpler to get the time zone from `TimeZone.getDefault()` so you don’t need a `Calendar` object.

Comment: Even on Android you may want to use the `java.time` classes rather than the not-good old  `Calendar`, `TimeZone` and `SimpleDateFormat`. For the time being it requires you to get the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). The newer classes are much more natural and convenient to use for a conversion job like yours.

Comment: @PiyushPatel thank you so much for the help, it works after I replaced the HH with hh.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks for the comment, I am using TimeZone.getDefault() to get timezone now.

Comment: You are Welcome @james

Answer (score 0):

Look I prepared function:-

```
public static String getUTCDate(String timestamp, String DateFormat) {
        SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm aa", Locale.getDefault());
        originalFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DateFormat, Locale.getDefault());
        targetFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        Date date = null;
        String formattedDate = null;
        try {
            date = originalFormat.parse(timestamp);
            formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return formattedDate;
    }
```

Get the value by calling -

```
Utils.getUTCDate("2017-04-24 01:00 AM", "HH:mm a")
```

Comment: Hey,Thanks for the answer, however your method does not work for me still I am getting the wrong output.

Comment: Give me your input. Make sure your input is `2017-04-24 01:00 AM` rather than `2017-04-24 1:00 AM`.

Comment: I have hard-coded the input as "2017-04-24 01:00 AM" it still returns "10:00 am" in android, works fine in my PC tho.

Comment: Still not working, your code is pretty similar with the one that I was using, it is fine in PC but always return "10:00 am" in Android.

Comment: I think Piyush Patel’s comment is valid here too: When you have am/pm marker, you may prefer `hh` for hour from 1 through 12 over uppercase `HH`  for hour from 0 through 23.

Comment: You are setting GMT time zone on *both* your formats? You are hardly getting any conversion to local time that way (I understood that this was a critical part of the requirements).